# plotly map not rendering in r viewer or 'view in new window'

Tags: r

Having issues with plotly.  Fairly new to plotly.  My issue:  script below (template taken directly from  plotly's site) does not render plotly scatter in R studio viewer.  I've tried opening in a new window as described here: [Plotly Maps Not Rendering in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465947/plotly-maps-not-rendering-in-r)

The code below was working previously (i.e. renders in the 'view new window'). Tried to use it yesterday and this morning; all I get is the title and colorbar.

```
 library(plotly)

    p2c_Map_Data$text <- with(p2c_Map_Data, 
                          paste(State, City, Zip, SalesCount, CustomerProspect,RevenuesProspect,
                          '<br>', "Days to Convert", MedianConversionTimeDays,'<br>',
                          "Touchpoint Count", MedianPathLength, "<br>",
                          "Sales", Revenues))

#give state boundaries a border
    l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 2)

# specify some map projection/options
    g <- list(
    scope = 'usa',
    projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
    showland = TRUE,
    landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
    subunitcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
    countrycolor = toRGB("gray85"),
    countrywidth = 0.5,
    subunitwidth = 0.5
    )

    p <- plot_geo(p2c_Map_Data, lat = ~latitude, lon = ~longitude) %>%
    add_markers(
    text = ~paste(p2c_Map_Data$State, p2c_Map_Data$City, p2c_Map_Data$Zip, 
                  paste("Sales Count:", p2c_Map_Data$SalesCount), 
                  paste("CustomerProspect:", p2c_Map_Data$CustomerProspect),
                  paste("Revenues:", p2c_Map_Data$Revenues),
                  paste("RevenuesProspect:", p2c_Map_Data$RevenuesProspect),
                  paste("Days to Convert:", p2c_Map_Data$MedianConversionTimeDays), 
                  paste("Touchpoint Count:", p2c_Map_Data$MedianPathLength), sep = "<br>"),
      color = ~p2c_Map_Data$Revenues, symbol = I("square"), size = I(10),      hoverinfo = "text") %>%
      colorbar(title = "Revenues") %>%
      layout(title = 'Map Data Report<br />FY 16', geo = g)
```

Comment: did you try expanding the Viewer pane/window? Just resizing it sometimes does it for me. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465947/plotly-maps-not-rendering-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hey Dan.  Yeah.  I tried that.  Looks  like your reference is similar to the link I mentioned.  That used to work.  Now, I only get the colorbar and title.